# Gitlab: Force non-interactive restore from backups?

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way to force a 'yes' to the question:

```
This will rebuild an authorized_keys file.
You will lose any data stored in authorized_keys file.
Do you want to continue (yes/no)?
```

When trying to restore from backups? I create a backup on server A, copy to my mirror on Server B and want to restore via a script on a cronjob.

I am running

```
Gitlab 6.2
GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.4 ? ... OK (1.7.9)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes; set the environment variable [`force` to `yes`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/6-2-stable/lib/tasks/gitlab/shell.rake#L28) for the rake process.

Answer (score 12):

With this syntax should work:

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=<BACKUP_ID> force=yes
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar to both Ash Wilson's and Andrés Cuadros Suárez's answers, I found the following also works (prepend with `sudo` if required)

```
gitlab-backup restore force=yes
```